# Convert a query string to a url

Tags: jquery, url, query-string

I'm new to manipulating url strings.

Bascially I have a form with numerous inputs the user can fill out. On submit the url format is like so:

```
  search.html?goingToArea=Yorkshire&leavingOn1=2013-11-26
```

Whats the best way to remove goingToArea and leavingOn1, and replace = with a / to make

```
 ..Yorkshire/2013-11-26/...
```

Most examples I've seen are either converting URL to a query string(the opposite of my question) or they return a JSON object, not a URL. I've looked at RegEx and jquery BBQ. Are these the right way to go? Its for a mobile site incase that helps any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Most of the time it's a lot easier to just catch the values on the serverside, and convert it to whatever you need there.

Comment: Here's the regex in C#, might be a start [\?!&].*?=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript "replace" function and Regex:

```
var urlString = "search.html?goingToArea=Yorkshire&leavingOn1=2013-11-26";
    urlString = urlString.replace(/\?(.+?)=/i, '/');
    urlString = urlString.replace(/\&(.+?)=/i, '/');

    console.log(urlString);
    // return => "search.html/Yorkshire/2013-11-26"
```

The first operation replace everything between a "?" and a "=" by a "/" (beginning or URL).

The second operation replace everything between a "&" and a "=" by a "/" (rest of URL).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex, but here is a non-regex solution. Not very elegant but it should work.

```
var splitted = "search.html?goingToArea=Yorkshire&leavingOn1=2013-11-26".split('&'); 
var place = splitted[0].split('=')[1]; 
var date = splitted[1].split('=')[1]; 
console.log(place + '/' + date);
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8FXNz/)***

Obviously, this assumes that the URL is in the right order. i.e., if `goingToArea` & `leavingOn1` are interchanged in the URL, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var qs = url.substring(url.indexof('?') + 1);
 var p = qs.split('&');
 var res = [];
 for( var i=0; i < p.length; p++ ) {
 var required_val = p.split('=')[1];
 res.push(required_val);
 } 

 var ans = url.substring(0, url.indexof('?')) + res.join('/');
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to do it in JS?

The best way will be to use webserver rewrite.

So if you are using Apache HTTP Server, take a look at mod_rewrite here - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html